# The entire column of cards expands with one click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

I created the cards for this tab using a loop, and the data is coming from a database.
When I click on the show more button, the entire visible column expands with it.
It does not show the content it's just expanding; the content is visible when I click Show More.
but if there is only one card in the line, it just expands that.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  Collapse,
  Button,
  Typography,
  Rating,
  useTheme,
  useMediaQuery,
} from "@mui/material";
import Header from "../../components/Header";
import { useGetProductsQuery } from "../../state/api";
import LinearProgress from "@mui/material/LinearProgress";

const Product = ({
  _id,
  name,
  description,
  price,
  rating,
  category,
  supply,
  stat,
}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Card
      sx={{
        backgroundImage: "none",
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.alt,
        borderRadius: "0.55rem",
      }}
    >
      <CardContent>
        <Typography
          sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}
          color={theme.palette.secondary[700]}
          gutterBottom
        >
          {category}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
          {name}
        </Typography>
        <Typography sx={{ mb: "1.5rem" }} color={theme.palette.secondary[400]}>
          ${Number(price).toFixed(2)}
        </Typography>
        <Rating value={rating} readOnly />

        <Typography variant="body2">{description}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button
          variant="primary"
          size="small"
          onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
          sx={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary[600] }}
        >
          See More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
      <Collapse
        in={isExpanded}
        timeout="auto"
        unmountOnExit
        sx={{
          color: theme.palette.neutral[300],
        }}
      >
        <CardContent>
          <Typography>id: {_id}</Typography>
          <Typography>Supply Left: {supply}</Typography>
          <Typography>
            Yearly Sales This Year: {stat[0].yearlySalesTotal}
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            Yearly Units Sold This Year: {stat[0].yearlyTotalSoldUnits}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
};

const Products = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetProductsQuery();
  const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1000px)");

  return (
    <Box m="1.5rem 2.5rem">
      <Header title="PRODUCTS" subtitle="See your list of products." />
      {data || !isLoading ? (
        <Box
          mt="20px"
          display="grid"
          gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
          justifyContent="space-between"
          rowGap="20px"
          columnGap="1.33%"
          sx={{
            "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4" },
          }}
        >
          {data.map(
            ({
              _id,
              name,
              description,
              price,
              rating,
              category,
              supply,
              stat,
            }) => (
              <Product
                key={_id}
                _id={_id}
                name={name}
                description={description}
                price={price}
                rating={rating}
                category={category}
                supply={supply}
                stat={stat}
              />
            )
          )}
        </Box>
      ) : (
        <>
          <LinearProgress
            color="primary"
            fourcolor="false"
            variant="indeterminate"
          />
        </>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

[This is the image of cards.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur2m8.png)

Well I expect it to expand only one card at a time

Comment: Could you please create StackBlitz URL so that we can assist you better and try to fix that issue?

Comment: unfortunately i can't
as I am learning most stuff now so I don't know now how to create it

Comment: So you want that if there is one card, instead of clicking the **some more** button, it should show the content directly, and if there is more than one card, then it should open only when clicked on the **Show More** button. Is that correct ?

Comment: No when i click show more of one card all other cards in the same column expands with one click

Comment: and if it's only on card in a column, like in mobile screen **then** only that cards expands

Comment: Ok So you want If clicked on the **Show More** button on any of the cards, then all of the cards clicked the **Show More** button automatically or opened the content, which means any of the cards clicked the **Show More** button, and within the same row, it expanded all of the text inside the **Show More** button.
And if there is only one card in the columns, then there is no need to have "Show More" button content visible just like that ?

Comment: look there are **Four Cards** visible in one column.
I clicked **See More** of only **One** Card within that column.
instead of only expanding **That** one card which I clicked, the entire column of **Four Cards** gets expands also

Comment: and it's does not show the the text inside **Show More** it's only expands the entire column of **Four** Cards
But if there is only one card only that Cards expands, then there is no problem

Comment: and I want for it to only expand One **Card** which I clicked

Comment: It seems there is only one "isExpanded" state for all cards. You should assign a separate state for each card

Comment: But I am getting data from **DataBase** so how can I assign separate state for each card?

Answer (score 0):

Created `isExpanded` inside the `Product` component, which should give each `Product` it's own independent state.

```js
const Product = ({
  _id,
  name,
  description,
  price,
  rating,
  category,
  supply,
  stat,
}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Card
      sx={{
        backgroundImage: 'none',
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        borderRadius: '0.55rem',
      }}
    >
      <CardContent>
        <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
          {category}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
          {name}
        </Typography>
        <Typography sx={{ mb: '1.5rem' }} color="text.secondary">
          ${Number(price).toFixed(2)}
        </Typography>
        <Rating value={rating} readOnly />

        <Typography variant="body2">{description}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          size="small"
          onClick={() => setIsExpanded((prev) => !prev)}
          sx={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main }}
        >
          {isExpanded ? 'See Less' : 'See More'}
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
      <Collapse
        in={isExpanded}
        timeout="auto"
        unmountOnExit
        sx={{
          color: theme.palette.text.primary,
        }}
      >
        <CardContent>
          <Typography>id: {_id}</Typography>
          <Typography>Supply Left: {supply}</Typography>
          <Typography>
            Yearly Sales This Year: {stat[0].yearlySalesTotal}
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            Yearly Units Sold This Year: {stat[0].yearlyTotalSoldUnits}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Here is the live code example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-epmcc9-tckxsy?file=Products.js)

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴlook the problem is still there, even in your **Stackblitz** demo if it's one card in column it works fine, but if there are **Four** all of them expands
You can check it also!